# How to setup multiple django projects to access the same database and models

Tags: python, django, architecture, intranet

I have one django project that serves as an API and contains a database and multiple apps with models, database migrations and so on.

I want to have a custom admin interface as well as django-admin which are only accessible via the intranet. Is this possible within the same django project while the other apps are accessible from outside the intranet? And if not, is it possible to have two django projects. One which serves as the API containing the database, models and migrations. And another one that contains just the django-admin and my custom admin interface app that can access the databse and models from the other project?